# No suitable constructor for Stripe

Tags: android, stripe-payments

The Error i got is 
error: no suitable constructor found for Stripe(StripeFormActivity,String)
constructor Stripe.Stripe() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Stripe.Stripe(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

```
Stripe stripe=new Stripe(StripeFormActivity.this,PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
                    stripe.createToken(
                    card,

                    new TokenCallback() {
                        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                            //getTokenList().addToList(token);

                            ProgressDialog.cancel();
                            cusRotateLoading.stop();

                            Log.d("token", "token = " + token.getId());
                            Intent ri = new Intent();
                            ri.putExtra("stripe_id", token.getId());
                            setResult(2, ri);
                            finish();
                        }




                            public void onError(Exception error) {
                                ProgressDialog.cancel();
                                cusRotateLoading.stop();
                                Common.showMkError(StripeFormActivity.this, error.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Hmm, why are you passing `StripeFormActivity.this` ? As far as I can tell that argument is meant to be a [Context](https://stripe.dev/stripe-android/com/stripe/android/Stripe.html#Stripe-context-publishableKey-). Try passing `new Stripe(getApplicationContext(),PUBLISHABLE_KEY);` for example, but basically you should be passing a Context.

Answer (score 0):

here is kotlin version

```
Stripe(this, stripePublicKey).createToken(card, object : ApiResultCallback<Token> {
                override fun onSuccess(token: Token) {

                    if (token.card != null) {

                    } else {
                        Utils.showToast(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong), this)
                    }
                }

                override fun onError(error: Exception) {
                    Utils.showToast(error.localizedMessage, this)
                }
            })
```

Here is java version

```
new Stripe(this, stripePublicKey).createToken(card, new ApiResultCallback<Token> {
                        override onSuccess(Token:token) {

                            if (token.card != null) {

                            } else {
                                Utils.showToast(getString(R.string.something_went_wrong), this)
                            }
                        }

                        override onError(Exception:error) {
                            Utils.showToast(error.localizedMessage, this)
                        }
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from `TokenCallback()` to new `ApiResultCallback<Token>()`. import `com.stripe.android.ApiResultCallback` and get latest version currently its `11.1.3`

So after changing it will be like

```
Stripe stripe=new Stripe(StripeFormActivity.this,PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

                        stripe.createToken(
                                cardToSave,
                                new ApiResultCallback<Token>() {
                                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull Token token) {
                                        //getTokenList().addToList(token);

                                        ProgressDialog.cancel();
                                        cusRotateLoading.stop();

                                        Log.d("token", "token = " + token.getId());
                                        Intent ri = new Intent();
                                        ri.putExtra("stripe_id", token.getId());
                                        setResult(2, ri);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                    public void onError(@NonNull Exception error) {
                                        ProgressDialog.cancel();
                                        cusRotateLoading.stop();
                                        Common.showMkError(StripeFormActivity.this, error.getLocalizedMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                        );
```

Comment: error: incompatible types: <anonymous ApiResultCallback<Token>> cannot be converted to TokenCallbac

Comment: Add this (`implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:11.1.3'`) dependecy in your app.gradle and sync your project.

Comment: Same Error as the first one

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version `12.8.2`, there are several APIs has been deprecated, see my solution below.

**Step 1:** Using latest dependency in gradle file

```
def stripe_version = "12.8.2"
implementation "com.stripe:stripe-android:$stripe_version"
```

**Step 2:** Change your code in `StripeFormActivity` to

```
Stripe stripe = new Stripe(StripeFormActivity.this, PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
stripe.createCardToken(card, new ApiResultCallback<Token>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
        //getTokenList().addToList(token);

        ProgressDialog.cancel();
        cusRotateLoading.stop();

        Log.d("token", "token = " + token.getId());
        Intent ri = new Intent();
        ri.putExtra("stripe_id", token.getId());
        setResult(2, ri);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NotNull Exception e) {
        ProgressDialog.cancel();
        cusRotateLoading.stop();
        Common.showMkError(StripeFormActivity.this, error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});
```